# What is the recommended thinset when tiling over concrete?

Tags: concrete, tile, ceramic-tile

I am about to start tiling a concrete area of my home about 220 sq feet. I was wondering if there is any specific type of thinset I should be using for a concrete surface. The tiles will be 12x12" ceramic tiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this type of [Flexbond](http://www.essentialhardware.com/product_detail.php?pid=200121&gdftrk=gdfV28536_a_7c3119_a_7c11872_a_7c200121&gclid=CjgKEAjw2KCcBRCQ_6mztcunhEgSJABPxOF1hIUb4TUfSF7AA10B9enSBslvAyVooTJ28PvR6wmIcfD_BwE) for concrete applications - well most applications.  This will isolate cracks up to 1/16th of an inch.  Also this stuff really bonds well to concrete.  I know that you can buy that $10 bag but I wouldn't skimp on the thinset.  I can say I have done a lot of tiling and not a crack yet (knock on concrete).

Also want to mention that I end up doing a lot of glass mosaic patterns (even in floors) and this stuff (get the white for glass) works great.

Comment: Yup, that's the stuff to use. Never skimp on the most important component of the floor system